# Grabbing a value from ngFor to use as a parameter in a nested form

Tags: angular, forms, ngfor

I have an array of terms I'm looping over to display some dictionary results, these results have links that are related to them. I have a small form per dictionary term that fires off a lambda function to run a stored procedure that adds a link. One of the parameters to add a link is the current dictionary terms ID. As far as I can tell from my Java error on the lambda side the function isn't getting the term ID sent over, so I feel like I'm doing something wrong when trying to grab the ID on the front-end.

**Template with form**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let term of terms">
      {{ term.term }} - {{ term.def }}
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let link of term.links">
          {{ link.name }} - {{ link.url }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="add-link">
        <form [formGroup]="addRelatedLinkForm" (ngSubmit)="addRelatedLinkSubmit(term.id, addRelatedLinkForm)">
          <input id="name" formControlName="name" type="text" placeholder="Link name">
          <input id="url" formControlName="url" type="text" placeholder="URL">
          <button type="submit">Add Related Link</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Add Related Link service**

```
addRelatedLink(token: String, id: Number, link: Link): Observable<any> {
    this.link_url = "http://localhost:4200/link";
    let body = {
      "name": link.name,
      "url": link.url,
      "term_id": id
    }
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    return this.http.post<any>(
      this.link_url,
      body,
      {
        headers: headers
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Component function**

```
addRelatedLinkForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    url: '',
    term_id: ''
  })


addRelatedLinkSubmit(id: number): void {
    this.termsService.getAWSToken().subscribe(token => {
      this.termsService.addRelatedLink(token.access_token, id, this.addRelatedLinkForm.value).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Problem solved, Roya made me realize a few things were off, after debugging, I noticed my data being sent over the wire was correct, I just wasn't matching some Java parameters on the Lambda side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is different between method definition and call!

where you call the method at template `addRelatedLinkSubmit(term.id, addRelatedLinkForm)` it has two arguments and in the component where you defined the method  `addRelatedLinkSubmit(id: number): void` there is one parameter that it accepts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! After your response, I was debugging and noticed all of the data was proper, turns out my id parameter wasn't matching 'termId' which is what Java was expecting in my Lambda function. Thanks!